# django not receiving POST data from nginx-upload-module

Tags: django, post, upload, nginx

please help me with that problem:
I have nginx-upload-module and nginx-progress-module
if i send form without nginx: I get POST data and request.FILES  -all norm
[image]
and I have no problem
opposite:
if i send that form with nginx
[image]
i get data of file (her size,name!! **but** i no have data of my form)
[image]
my code:
#url.py

```
urlpatterns = patterns('apps.test_doc.views',
    url(r'^test$','initial', name='initial'),
    url(r'^test/upload/$','upload', name="upload"),
)
```

#js

```
<form id="upload" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" onsubmit="progress();">  
document.getElementById('upload').action = "/upload/share?X-Progress-ID=" + id;;
```

#view.py

```
@csrf_exempt
def initial(request):
    data = {
    'form': UploadForm(),
    }
    return render_to_response('upload.html', data, RequestContext(request))

def upload(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        pathfile = request.POST.get('file.path')
        upfile = os.path.basename(pathfile)
        form = UploadForm(request.POST,initial={'file':upfile})
    
        if form.is_valid():
            cd = form.cleaned_data
            instance = form.save(commit=False)
            instance.save()  
return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('initial'))
```

#nginx.conf

```
location = /upload/share {
    upload_pass /test/upload/;
    client_max_body_size 250m;
    upload_store /tmp;
    upload_set_form_field $upload_field_name.name "$upload_file_name";
    upload_set_form_field $upload_field_name.content_type "$upload_content_type";
    upload_set_form_field $upload_field_name.path "$upload_tmp_path";
    upload_aggregate_form_field "$upload_field_name.md5" "$upload_file_md5";
    upload_aggregate_form_field "$upload_field_name.size" "$upload_file_size";
    upload_cleanup 400 404 499 500-505;
    
    upload_limit_rate 16k;
    track_uploads upload 1m;
} 

location = /upload/status {
    report_uploads upload;
}

location / {
    proxy_pass_header Server;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Scheme $scheme;
    proxy_connect_timeout 90s;
    proxy_read_timeout 30s;
    proxy_pass http://localhost:8152/;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    track_uploads upload 30s;
}
```

where me find that problem:  **Nginx, Django, JS** ?

add (rest html):

```
<form id="upload_form"  method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" accept-charset="utf-8" class="steps" onsubmit="progress();">{% csrf_token %}
<h3>Upload a new file</h3>
    {{form.as_p}}
 <input type="submit" value="Upload" id="submit" /></p> 
 </form>
    <div id="status" style="display: none;">
  <table width="100%"> 
    <tr><th></th><th>load</th><th>rest</th><th>all</th></tr>
    <tr><td>time:</td><td id="elapsed">∞</td><td id="remaining">∞</td><td id="total">∞</td></tr>
    <tr><td>size:</td><td id="sent">0 b</td><td id="offset">0 b</td><td id="length">0 b</td></tr>
    <tr><td>speed:</td><td id="speed">n/a</td></tr>
  </table>
  <div style="border: 1px solid #c0c0c0;">
      <div style="background: #c0c0c0; width: 0%; text-align: right;" id="bar">0%</div>
  </div>
```

#js (all)

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
    function progress() {
    var ms = new Date().getTime() / 1000;
    rq = 0;
    id = "";
    for (i = 0; i < 32; i++) {
      id += Math.floor(Math.random() * 16).toString(16);
    }
    document.getElementById('upload_form').action = "/upload/share?X-Progress-ID=" + id;;
    document.getElementById('status').style.display = 'block'
    interval = window.setInterval(function () { fetch(id, ms); }, 1000);
    return true;
  }
  function fetch(id, ms) {
    var fetch = new XMLHttpRequest();
    fetch.open("GET", "/upload/status", 1);
    fetch.setRequestHeader("X-Progress-ID", id);
    fetch.onreadystatechange = function () {
      if (fetch.readyState == 4) {
        if (fetch.status == 200) {
          var now = new Date().getTime() / 1000;
          var upload = eval(fetch.responseText);
          if (upload.state == 'uploading') {
            var diff = upload.size - upload.received;
            var rate = upload.received / upload.size;
            var elapsed = now - ms;
            var speed = upload.received - rq; rq = upload.received;
            var remaining = (upload.size - upload.received) / speed;
            var uReceived = parseInt(upload.received) + ' bytes';
            var uDiff = parseInt(diff) + ' bytes';
            var tTotal = parseInt(elapsed + remaining) + ' secs';
            var tElapsed = parseInt(elapsed) + ' secs';
            var tRemaining = parseInt(remaining) + ' secs';
            var percent = Math.round(100*rate) + '%';
            var uSpeed = speed + ' bytes/sec';
            document.getElementById('length').firstChild.nodeValue = parseInt(upload.size) + ' bytes';
            document.getElementById('sent').firstChild.nodeValue = uReceived;
            document.getElementById('offset').firstChild.nodeValue = uDiff;
            document.getElementById('total').firstChild.nodeValue = tTotal;
            document.getElementById('elapsed').firstChild.nodeValue = tElapsed;
            document.getElementById('remaining').firstChild.nodeValue = tRemaining;
            document.getElementById('speed').firstChild.nodeValue = uSpeed;
            document.getElementById('bar').firstChild.nodeValue = percent;
            document.getElementById('bar').style.width = percent
          }
          else {
            window.clearTimeout(interval);
          }
        }
      }
    }
    fetch.send(null);
  }
</script>
```

i need save in model data form and path to file

*i wrote to* **creator nginx-upload-midule** that  question
solving this problem simple need add in location directive:
**upload_pass_form_field**
example: upload_pass_form_field "^my_name_field$|^description$";
thanks to **Valery Kholodkov**

Comment: Please post the rest of the form html

Comment: your `form = UploadForm(request.POST,initial={'file':upfile})` has `no request.FILES`

Comment: when you upload an image or a file you need to put the `request.FILES`

Comment: yes, method that you mention is standard method use form field. But other way use upload form field is nginx-upload-module. You may try